# How to get all files under a folder in my project

Tags: java, file, loops

The folder is `/src/img`. I need to get all file names(`png` files) from `img` folder and all subfolders.I dont know the full path to the folder so i need only to focus the project resourse. I need them in array. Using Java8 and Eclipse Mars.
So far this works:

```
try {


Files.walk(Paths.get("/home/fixxxer/NetBeansProjects/Installer/src/img/")).forEach(filePath -> {
            if (Files.isRegularFile(filePath)) {
                System.out.println(filePath);
            }
        });
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(InstallFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

The problem is that the folder need to be called like this:
`/img` cause it is inside the project
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: The link you sent me is what ive tried so far. I need to focus only the local folder. In my case i dont know the full path to the folder cause user might be different...

Comment: so can you please unmark it or answer it...

Comment: Your question states *The folder is `/src/img`* so I'm not sure why you say you don't know the path to it.

Comment: yes but it is a project folder, not an OS folder